# How to complete a Rx Observable depending on a condition in a event

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a event that I'm not in control of which provides me with data. The eventArgs looks something like this:

```
class MyEventArg {
  bool IsLastItem {get;}
  Data DataItem {get;}
}
```

I use Rx to convert this event to an IObservable. But I want to complete the observable if IsLastItem is true.

Any elegant ideas? One way would be to pipe the data through a subject that I have more control over to set the OnComplete event if the condition occurs...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the last element to be included you can merge a stream with only the last element together with the regular stream combined with `TakeWhile`.
Here is a simple console app to prove it:

```
var subject = new List<string>
{                            
"test",
"last"
}.ToObservable();

var my = subject
            .Where(x => x == "last").Take(1)
            .Merge(subject.TakeWhile(x => x != "last"));

my.Subscribe(
    o => Console.WriteLine("On Next: " + o), 
    () => Console.WriteLine("Completed"));

Console.ReadLine();
```

This prints:

```
On Next: test
On Next: last
Completed
```

**UPDATE**
There was a bug that supressed the OnCompleted message if the underlying Observable didn't actually complete. I corrected the code to ensure `OnCompleted` gets called

And if you want to avoid subscribing to the underlying sequence multiple times for cold observables you can refactor the code like this:

```
var my = subject.Publish(p => p
            .Where(x => x == "last").Take(1)
            .Merge(p.TakeWhile(x => x != "last")));
```

Comment: Nice! Took me a few seconds to see how it's done. Maybe better write: subject.TakeWhile(x => x != "last").Merge(subject.Where(x => x == "last").Take(1));
The cold observable tip is a +. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
public static IObservable<TSource> TakeWhileInclusive<TSource>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    return Observable
        .Create<TSource>(o => source.Subscribe(x =>
                                                   {
                                                       o.OnNext(x);
                                                       if (!predicate(x))
                                                           o.OnCompleted();
                                                   },
                                               o.OnError,
                                               o.OnCompleted
                                  ));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
IObservable<MyEventArg> result =
    myEventArgObservable.TakeWhile(arg => !arg.IsLastItem);
```

Comment: Wow, that would simple and nice. Do you know if the Observable completes if the predicate is true?

Comment: Yes, it will notify OnCompleted() if you don't want it to notify OnCompleted you can simply use Where(arg => !arg.IsLastItem)

Comment: Yes, it seems like the Observable completes, BUT now I have the problem that I won't receive the last item...