# ReactiveCocoa takeUntil and takeWhile doesn't send last "next"

Tags: objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

Consider the following snippet:

```
- (RACSignal *)startRouting {
...
}

- (RACSignal *)updateRoutingWithSession:(NSString *)session {
...
}

- (RACSignal *)fetchFlights {
    return [[self startRouting] flattenMap:^RACStream *(NSString *session) {
        return [[[[self updateRoutingWithSession:session]
                        delay:2.0f]
                        repeat]
                        takeUntilBlock:^BOOL(RACTuple *operationAndResponse) {
                            AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [operationAndResponse first];
                            NSDictionary *response = [operationAndResponse second];
                            return [operation isCancelled] || 100 == [response[kPercentComplete] intValue];
                        }];
    }];
}
```

What's happening here is that `startRouting` returns a `RACSignal` which sends a session ID.
`updateRoutingWithSession:` returns a `RACSignal` which sends an `NSDictionary` looking including a `PercentComplete` attribute. There's a two second delay between polls.

`fetchFlights` will run until `updateRoutingWithSession:` has a `PercentComplete` of 100.

My issue here is that the very last `sendNext:`, where the `takeUntilBlock` returns `true`, doesn't reach the `RACSubscriber`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this in the world of RX. This is commonly solved by merging two signals. One that takes the repeated source until the the predicate is true. And the other that skips while the predicate is true.

This looks something like this

```
 BOOL (^finished)(id _) = ^BOOL(id _) {
    return predicate; // BOOLean here
}

// You want a multicast signal, because multiple signals will subscribe to the source.
// Multicasting it means that you won't get repeated api-requests, in this case.
RACMulticastConnection *source = [[theSignal repeat] publish];

RACSignal *whileNotDone = [source.signal takeUntilBlock:finished];
RACSignal *whenDone = [[source.signal skipUntilBlock:finished] take:1];
RACSignal *merged = [RACSignal merge:@[whileNotDone, whenDone]];

[source connect]; // Needed for a multicast signal to initiate.
```

The `merged` signal will `sendNext` every `next` in `source` including the very last one. Then `sendCompleted`.

Some references from the world of RX:

- ["How to complete a Rx Observable depending on a condition in a event"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126495/how-to-complete-a-rx-observable-depending-on-a-condition-in-a-event)
- ["RX Observable.TakeWhile checks condition BEFORE each element but I need to perform the check after"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697658/rx-observable-takewhile-checks-condition-before-each-element-but-i-need-to-perfo)

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: your problem is that the `next` that triggers the completion is not sent out? `takeUntilBlock` will propagate the nexts until the predicate is NO. ([documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACStream.h#L265))  Therefore, the last `next` will not be sent. But you can subscribe to `completion` which should happen in this case.

Comment: Absolutely correct. What I could do is not use takeUntilBlock and instead move the predicate into the updateRoutingWithSession: and only sendComplete: once PercentComplete is 100. But that would break the logical flow of updateRoutingWithSession: which is oblivious to how higher order functions use it, i.e. it is not aware that the idea is to poll the service until complete.

Comment: @HansSjunnesson I think @allprog is trying to point out that you can use the `completed` event here to find out when the `takeUntilBlock:` returns `NO`. You can do this through `-subscribeCompleted:` or an operator like [-sequenceNext:](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/2b98e161af39dd11f1a00ca35fae1607dbb6b0ee/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L163-L164).

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers True, but completed doesn't send any data. I'm interested in the contents of the last, completing value that the signal sends. TakeWhile suppresses the propagation of that last `next`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't understand that part. In that case, you could combine some other operators, like `-mapPreviousWithStart:combine:` and `-materialize`, to hold onto the previous value and then treat completion as a value in and of itself.